# How can I use Custom Attributes for devices in order to get Version number of Products

Tags: android, flutter, vmware, mdm, airwatch

My requirement is to get all products from console for Android app along with version name.  If I query `deviceExtensive` search from `Postman`, getting information of all `Products`(apps) in all devices in one go like `ProductId`, `Name`, `Status` but not getting `Version` of Product.

Same problem with `productExtensive` search, getting all information of products except version number. I have nearly 20 products.

Is there any `service` available in [document](https://resources.workspaceone.com/view/zv5cgwjrcv972rd6fmml/en) where I can get version number of all device available in serve.

OR

Can [`Custom attributes`](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workspace-ONE-UEM/services/WinRugg_Platform/GUID-AWT-CREATECUSTOMATTRIBUTEPAYLOAD.html) serve my purpose?

But no idea we can add `Custom attributes` payload groups level because device level is possible as we thousands of devices.

Comment: `String versionName = context.getPackageManager()
    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName`

Comment: @Code - Thanks for your input, I need it from vmware airwatch services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only can get `version number` of applications `device` level instead of getting server level.

Use `loop` and pass `deviceId` in every iteration.

There is no api available in AW rest service document. Below service you can use to do so

```
https://host/api/mdm/devices/apps?searchby=Serialnumber&id=R10QA7AL&page=1&pagesize=50
https://host/api/mdm/devices/apps?searchby=ImeiNumber&id=YourID&page=1&pagesize=50
https://host/api/mdm/devices/apps?searchby=Udid&id=YourID&page=1&pagesize=50
https://host/api/mdm/devices/apps?searchby=Macaddress&id=YourID&page=1&pagesize=50
```

`Custom attributes` can only be used for device level not `groups` level then again this not going to solve your problem.